# The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded - what gives?

Tags: mono

Using the Raspbian Wheezy image...

I installed the mono runtime like so on my Raspberry PI:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mono-runtime
```

and it seemed to install fine (If I run `mono` I get a sensible command output).

Then I started MonoDevelop up up my mac and created a "Hello World" console application (you know, just what you get when you go New Solution | Console Application) - compiled and ran - no problem.

Now I copied the exe over to the PI and was expecting that I could just go:

```
mono HelloWorld.exe
```

but when I do so I get this error:

> The assembly mscorlib.dll was not found or could not be loaded.
>   It should have been installed in the `/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll' directory.

Now I am confused - what have I done wrong and how should I get that DLL?  Is there another package I should install?

Comment: What version of .net is is targeted for. It should not be pipelined either.

Comment: Do you have that file (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll)? Do you have anything at all in /usr/lib/mono?

Comment: @ppumkin - I am targeting "Mono / .NET 3.5"

Comment: @SteveRobillard - That worked - thanks!!  Maybe post it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the mono-complete package (which includes the mscorlib.dll file); to do this enter the following at the command line.

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case I was writing the wrong name of the HelloWord.exe file. When I wrote correctly i.e. mono Helloword.exe, it worked fine. However the error was the same one

Comment: If mono HelloWord.exe report some missing dll, the problem is somewhere else.